# Run a fan 5scs long GPIO

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python, python-3

```
def fan_on():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    FAN_PIN = 23
    GPIO.setup(FAN_PIN,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(FAN_PIN,True)
```

This is my code to run a fan on my rpi via GPIO

How can i run the fan in 5 scs long?

Comment: Perhaps switch it on, wait for 5 seconds, switch it off.  What search terms have you used?

Answer (score 0):

since you already configured the gpio pins in the fan_on function you would just run, GPIO.output(FAN_PIN,False). you would also need the library time and more specifically the sleep function. in the end your python3 code would look something like this,

```
import RPI.GPIO
from time import sleep

def fan_on():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    FAN_PIN = 23
    GPIO.setup(FAN_PIN,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(FAN_PIN,True)

while True:
    fan_on()
    sleep(5)
    GPIO.output(FAN_PIN,False)
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: Sir is it possible to run the sleep on different threas because it makes the whole script sleep TIA